# assign values to vector in a dataframe based on conditions from other vectors in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

so I have a partially empty dataframe and I need to assign values to a vector that we may call "C" based on different outcomes of an other vector which we may call B. The values to assign to C are taken, in some determined cases, from a third vector, "A". How can I do that? I tried if statements and for loops but don't know how to do them properly. Here's summarized my problem. 
Thank you for your answers

```
A = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

B = (1,0,1,2,1,0,0,2,0,1)

C = 0            if B = 0  
  =A(same row)   if B = 1
  =-A(same row)  if B =-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to get the `sign` of 'B' and multiply with 'A'

```
C <- sign(B) * A
```